# Java Как переписать код с AsyncTask на Executor?

Tags: java, android

Есть достаточно простой код на java, погодное приложение для android.
Но оно написано с AsyncTask, подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно переписать его с использованием Executor? Я DownloadWeatherTask отражаю  в newSingleThreadExecutor(), а onPostExecute вrunOnUiThread, но на сколько это правильно, не знаю? И куда можно вынести этот код из MainActivity?

```
private class DownloadWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            URL url = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line = reader.readLine();
                while (line != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                    line = reader.readLine();
                }
                return result.toString();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                String city = jsonObject.getString("name");
                String temp = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp");
                String description = jsonObject.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getString("description");
                String weather = String.format("%s\nТемпература: %s\nНа улице: %s", city, temp, description);
                textViewWeather.setText(weather);
                Integer tempIm = jsonObject.getJSONObject("main").getInt("temp");
                if (tempIm <= 1) {
                    mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.snow);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас и AsyncTask не очень корректно реализован - парсить JSON надо было в doInBackground и в onPostExecute выдавать уже распаршенные данные.

На Executor это будет примерно так выглядеть (пишу без IDE, могут быть опечатки):

```
public class Data {
    String city;
    String temp;
    String description;
    String weather;
    Integer tempIm;
}

public interface Callback {
    void doOnSuccess(Data data);
    void doOnError(Exception e);
}

public class Task {

    Callback callback;
    
    public Task(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    
    public void run() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
            try {
            // тут сетевой запрос и парсинг JSON и создание и наполенение экземпляра Data класса
                callback.doOnSuccess(data);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                callback.doOnError(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Соответственно в активити используйте так:

```
new Task(new Callback {
    void doOnSuccess(Data data) {
        runOnUiThread(()-> {
            //тут вывод результата во вьюхи 
        })
    }
    void doOnError(Exception e) {
        //тут вывод ошибки
    }
}).run();
```

По факту от AsyncTask отличий считай и нет. Лучше уже RxJava использовать. Типа примерно так:

```
new Task()
       .run()
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(
           data -> {/*вывод результат во вьюхи*/},
           error-> {/*вывод c*/}
       );
```

Comment: класс task мог бы пригодиться чтобы возвращать данные в main thread, чтоб не писать runOnUiThread в колбэках, а так смысла в нем нет, к тому же создавать в нем executor тоже не стоит каждый раз... в случае rx или livedata или flow колбэки тоже не нужны...